# how to install npm libraries that list lower version of react as peer dependency than installed version

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering how I might be able to install a library such as react-progressive-graceful-image which lists react 17 as the highest version of react as a peer dependency in a project that has react 18 installed. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can install it as you would usually. Just npm install, and you'll receive warnings, but it'll allow you to go forward if it's what you really want to do. Forgive me if you tried that and it didn't work?